# AMD64 assembly PINSRB & PEXTRB

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm new to assembly and have to understand the following lines:

```
PINSRB $0x00, %r10d, %xmm8
PEXTRB $0x00 , %xmm9, (%rdx, %rcx)
```

I know that the PINSRB inserts a word into the xmm8 register, but what does the $0x00 mean? Is it some kind of an offset?
And what exactly does the instruction (%rdx, %rcx) mean?

regards

Comment: And you tried searching for PINSRB docs prior asking, right?

Comment: I've searched but haven't found a satisfying answer. I posted this question here because I'm a bit nervous and hoped that someone could help me. I just don't know what the instructions $0x00 and ($rdx, %rcx) mean.

Comment: Um, PINSRB does not insert a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first operand to `PINSRB` is an immediate operand and specifies a count.

You can get information in Intel's or AMD's manuals.  See  http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf, (the reference manual for Intel instructions), page 4-114.  Please note, though, that Intel's documentation specifies instruction operands in reverse order (Intel syntax) from the one you are using.  Many people have taken this information and put them in a more convenient form, for example [this page](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PINSRB%3aPINSRD%3aPINSRQ.html) explains it pretty well, I think.

The notation `(%rdx, %rcx)` means the memory location whose address is the sum of the contents of `%rdx` and `%rcx`.  So if `%rdx` contained 500 and `%rcx` contained 200 then the expression would refer to memory location 700.

Aside: Since you asked about the meaning of a simple address expression, it would appear you are new to assembly.  Hope you enjoy it!  But when you are just learning the basics, like addressing, it would seem that it would take a while to also fully comprehend the intricacies of SSE4 instructions. :)  Welcome to assembly :)  I would say "hope that helps" but PINSRB doesn't seem like a great place to *start*.  Cheers. :)

Comment: thanks for that great answer...it helped me a lot :). Maybe someday I can enjoy the assembly language :D